# behat mink equivalent of dropdown->selectOptionByText()?

Tags: behat, mink

I'm working with Selenium and behat mink for the first time.  I have the following code:

```
$category_dropdown = $this->find('xpath', "//select[@name=\"category\"]");
echo $category_dropdown->getHtml();
$category->selectOptionByText('Take Out);
```

and the output is:

```
<option value="183">Fast Food</option>
<option value="186">Take Out</option>
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method Behat\Mink\Element\NodeElement::selectOptionByText()
```

The line `$category->selectOptionByText('Take Out');` causes errors because the function selectOptionByText doesn't actually exist.  Is there another way to achieve the intended behaviour?

*I'm so new to all this that I'm still trying to figure out the online documentation for this framework.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were close...
Try to use

```
$category->selectOption('Take Out');
```

Here is the [LINK](http://apigen.juzna.cz/doc/Behat/Mink/class-Behat.Mink.Element.NodeElement.html) to all the methods from NodeElement class

And by the way there is already Gherkin method which can help you
`I select "([^"]|\"*)" from "([^"]|\"*)"`
which in your case is

```
I select "Take Out" from "category"
```

Here is the [LIST](https://github.com/Behat/MinkExtension/blob/master/src/Behat/MinkExtension/Context/MinkContext.php) of already available Gherkin methods

Comment: I'm getting `select option with value|text "1" not found. (Behat\Mink\Exception\ElementNotFoundException)`  DO you know why?  I supplied the text "Take Out" but why does it evaluate it to the number 1?

Comment: If I change the text to "Take Out blahblah", then I get the error `select option with value|text "Take Out blahblah" not found. (Behat\Mink\Exception\ElementNotFoundException)`.  That's weird that Take Out reports the number 1, but Take Out blahblah reports Take Out blahblah...

Comment: thats strange..what if try to set option "Fast Food"?. Can you paste all html select element

Comment: Fast Food also gives me the "1" error.  If I try to select any value that's actually in the select items, then I get 1 error, otherwise I get the "whatever text I put in" error.   I'll see if I can simplify the problem even more

Comment: Oh wait, i see where you're going..  I think I'm confusing this error with another select option elsewhere in my tests.  That's probably it.

Comment: yeah...so this step is successfully passed and then another one with "1" is failed.. probably